# Sass compiling to simple css

Tags: css, sass

i'm having this issue where Sass isn't doing what it should do:
*Here is an example*

```
.main {
  display: flex;
}
```

*Should output*

```
.main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

*Is outputting*

```
.main{display:flex}
```

I ran :
`sass --watch assets/scss:assets/css/ --style=compressed`

The output i'm expecting works with the VSCODE extension, but i want to use wsl to do this. If anyone could help i'd be very happy!

Comment: Check [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations#interpolation)

Comment: +1 @Doc-Han Thanks very much man! I'm looking on it, and i see how it works :) I though it would come with scss but never knew i had to do it myself !!!

Comment: Most projects I worked with use a chain of tools to do this: fist sass to transpile SASS or SCSS down to normal CSS, and then a second step [to add vendor-specific prefixes](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)

Comment: Yes, sass and autoprefixer are different tools! :)